# Different report results between Google Analytics 4 UI and Google Data API data

Tags: python, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I have a list of customers set in GA4 and I am using the [google API analytics for GA4](https://github.com/googleapis/python-analytics-data#installation) to retrieve daily the traffic metrics for reporting purposes.

Checking the metrics day by day, I noticed a lot of differences in the metrics between the GA UI web and the answer given by google API.

I thought that there was an error in the logic of my pipeline but I obtained the SAME VALUES, testing THE SAME REQUEST by [runReport from the official google guide](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/data/v1/rest/v1beta/properties/runReport)
using:

- property id
- JSON request body:

```
{
 "dimensions": [
   {
     "name": "date"
   },
   {
     "name": "deviceCategory"
   },
   {
     "name": "hostName"
   },
   {
     "name": "pagePathPlusQueryString"
   },
   {
     "name": "pageTitle"
   },
   {
     "name": "sessionDefaultChannelGrouping"
   }
 ],
 "metrics": [
   {
     "name": "engagedSessions"
   },
   {
     "name": "newUsers"
   },
   {
     "name": "screenPageViews"
   },
   {
     "name": "sessions"
   },
   {
     "name": "userEngagementDuration"
   }
 ],
 "dateRanges": [
   {
     "startDate": "yesterday",
     "endDate": "yesterday"
   }
 ],
 "metricAggregations": [
   "TOTAL"
 ]
}
```

After some tests, I realized that I retrieve higher and wrong values ONLY when I use in the API RunReportRequest the dimensions "PagePathPlusQueryString" and/or "pagePath" and/or "pageTitle".

The only way that allows me to obtain the perfect match between GA API and Google Analytics Web UI is by removing these values.

I didn't see any limitations or best practices about the dimensions above need to be included in a request, so I don't understand where the error is and why I get the wrong values.

Please, can you help me?

Comment: Please edit the question and add the data extracted from GA API and UI. Also share the code snippets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Report UI you can download the report from Google Analytics.
As you can see, if you make the SUM in google sheet, the total amount is different from the GRAND TOTAL provided by the UI

It is a BUG!

[image]